# MongoDB C++ driver BSON() usage to generate BSON with null values

Tags: c++, mongodb, bson

Is there a way of using BSON() macro from the MongoDB C++ driver in order to generate a BSON will null value. For examples, in order to generate a BSON to represent this document: `{"a": "foo", "b": null}`:

```
BSONObj myObj = BSON("a" << "foo" << "b" << <something that I don't know>);
```

I have tried with this (naïve) approach but it doesn't work:

```
BSONObj myObj = BSON("a" << "foo" << "b" << NULL);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to do:

```
BSONObj myObj = BSON("a" << "foo" << "b" << BSONNULL);
```

See [this tutorial file](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/6f960668619ade57386a7c699fca14b4ea37e118/src/mongo/client/examples/tutorial.cpp#L61-L63) for another example.

Comment: Exactly that! Thanks!